# how to load set of HTML files in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some training modules which I want to load from my MVC site (SSL). I am trying run them as following but it does not load their css and images. Also I am not sure if it will let me to move to other html pages with in the same module by clicking the links on index.html.

Can anyone please suggest me a batter way of doing?

```
public ActionResult DisplayModule(string path)
{
    return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where are the *css* and *images* and how are included?

Comment: css and images are in folders. Each e-learning module is a separate folder (html project) which contains its own style and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CSS and Images are all under one HTML package, I don't think you will get that sort of flexibility with `FilePathResult`. Also with that you will struggle to get links working because if you click on links they will be relative.

I think if you add your e-learning modules as virtual directory to your web application in IIS, and then redirect directly, that will sort your purpose.

```
<a href="\myVirtualDirectory\<%:model.Path %>">my Course</a>
```